# Idenitfying $P\mathbb{B}(l^2(\Gamma))P$ with the matrix algebra $M_{F}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functional-analysis, representation-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group. Let $F \subset \Gamma$ be a finite set. Let $E=\text{span}\{\delta_g: g \in F\}$. Then $E$ is a closed in $l^2(\Gamma)$ and $l^2(\Gamma)=E \oplus {E}^\perp$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $E$ (defined by $P(x)=e$, when $x=e+e^{\perp}$). I want to identify $P\mathbb{B}(l^2(\Gamma))P$ with the matrix algebra $M_{F}(\mathbb{C})$.

For $f \in l^2(\Gamma)$, we have $f=\sum_{t\in \Gamma}f(t)\delta_t$. So I have $$P(f)=\sum_{t \in F}f(t)\delta_t$$

Hence, I can write $P=\sum_{t \in F}\delta_t$ by representing $\delta_tf$ as $f(t)\delta_t$. I can think of $P$ as the $(|F| \times |F|$) matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\0&1 & \ldots&0\\\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\0 &0 &\ldots &1
\end{bmatrix}$$
For $\lambda_s \in \mathbb{B}(l^2(\Gamma))$ ( where $\lambda_s$ is defined by $\lambda_s(\delta_t)=\delta_{st}$), we have $$P\lambda_sP(f)=P\lambda_s\left(\sum_{t \in F}f(t)\delta_t\right)=P\left(\sum_{t \in F}f(t)\delta_{st}\right)=\sum_{t \in F  \cap s^{-1}F}f(t)\delta_{st}=\sum_{t \in F \cap sF}(\delta_{s^{-1}t}\otimes\delta_t)f$$

So I can write $$P\lambda_sP=\sum_{t \in F \cap sF}\delta_{s^{-1}t}\otimes\delta_t$$

If I let $\{e_{p,q}\}_{p,q \in F}$ be the canonical matrix units of $M_{F}(\mathbb{C})$, then the book I am following tells me that $$P\lambda_sP=\sum_{p \in F \cap sF}e_{p,s^{-1}p}$$

My question is : Are these two representations the same? Is the canonical matrix unit of the form $\delta_s\delta_t$?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: How to get $\sum_{t \in F  \cap s^{-1}F}f(t)\delta_{st}=\sum_{t \in F \cap sF}(\delta_{s^{-1}t}\otimes\delta_t)f$

Comment: $(\delta_{s^{-1}t} \otimes \delta_t)f=\langle f,\delta_t \rangle \delta_{s^{-1}t}=f(t)\delta_{s^{-1}t}$

Comment: So In the equation $P\lambda_sP=\sum_{t \in F \cap sF}\delta_{s^{-1}t}\otimes\delta_t$,we should reverse the order of $\delta_{s^{-1}t}$ and $\delta_t$.

Comment: No. Observe that before the last equality, $t \in F \cap s^{-1}F$ where as in the last entry, $t \in F \cap sF$

Comment: $\sum_{t \in F  \cap s^{-1}F}f(t)\delta_{st}=\sum_{u \in F  \cap sF}f(s^{-1}u)\delta_{u}$,$(\delta_{s^{-1}u} \otimes \delta_u)f=\langle f,\delta_u \rangle \delta_{s^{-1}u}=f(u)\delta_{s^{-1}u}$

Comment: Yeah. This is the  calculation.